# GeoHashUtils Library not working as expected

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, geohashing

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> geoList = Arrays.asList("t9yu8v", "vtejpg", "t9yu8Y", "vtejpg", "t9yu8Y");
        for(String s : geoList) {
            try {
                GeoHashUtils.bbox(s);
                System.out.println("Success in " + s);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception in " + s);
            }
        }
    }
```

org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoHashUtils.java is the class present in maven dependency of elastic search version 6.5.0/6.8.23
This code sometimes giving success, sometimes throwing exception for the same geohash

```
Output - 
Success in t9yu8v
Success in vtejpg
Exception in t9yu8Y
Success in vtejpg
Exception in t9yu8Y
```

In the first run, vtejpg giving success, but giving exception in subsequent run.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example it works with `t9yu8v` and `vtejpg` but fails on `t9yu8Y`, which makes sense since the last one is not correct geohash from Elasticsearch's perspective.The last character in it is invalid.

That is expected behavior, but the intermittent error with `vtejpg` that you are describing in your question is not really possible since there is no state in this utility class that would behave differently in sequential runs.